# Can't open serial port via minicom, but fine via Python and shell

Tags: ubuntu, python, minicom

I have been having issues with connecting to serial ports via `minicom` the last two weeks. For some reason, `/dev/ttyACM0` maps to `tty8` when I try to connect to it. My user is member of the dialout group, and the permissions on `/dev/ttyACM0` seem to be set correctly.

```
$ minicom -d /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200
minicom: cannot open /dev/tty8: Permission denied


$ ll /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialoot 166, 0 Aug 16 12:02 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I also tried to setup a connection with `pyserial`, and this behaves as I expect..

```
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
>>> ser.write(b"Hello\n")
10
>>> ser.readline()
b'Hello\r\n"
>>> ser.readline()
b'Hello: command not found\r\n'
>>> ser.close()
```

I tried installing the latest system updates (I run `Zorin OS`, based on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`) and rebooting several times. I also tried different USB ports, without results. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong with my setup here?

Edit: I just got the idea to communicate directly via my shell, and this seems to be working. I therefore think it is a minicom issue. Still very strange, since I can't find other people with the same problem.

```
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0
$ echo "Hello\n" > /dev/ttyACM0
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0
Hello
Hello: command not found
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

```
minicom -D  /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200
```

Hint: `D` is a capital letter.

Comment: Ah thanks! I used to do it  without any letter actually (just minicom /dev/ttyACM0). However, in retrospect, I think that worked because I had /dev/ttyACM0 set in the config. Therefore, it would fetch the right port, despite that I was giving the wrong argument. I think that somehow, the config got removed, and then it actually stopped working :).

Comment: And thanks for Stephen.